# Passing multiple objects in a form_for to update all objects at once with namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass in multiple object in a rails form_for with an admin namespace.  I'm getting an error that says `undefined method 'model_name' for Array:Class

This is the view I'm trying to run:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @observation_reads] do |f|  %>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <% @observation_reads.each do |observation_read| %>
           <tr>
             <ul class="admin-employee">
               <td><%= check_box_tag "observation_read_ids[]", observation_read.id %></td>
               <td><li><%= observation_read.employee_id_observer %></li></td>
               <td><li><%= select_tag(observation_read.id, options_for_select(@readers))  %></li></td>
               <td><li><%= select_tag(observation_read.id, options_for_select(@readers))  %></li></td>
               <td><li><%= select_tag(observation_read.id, options_for_select(@readers))  %></li></td>
             </ul>
           </tr>
       <% end %>
      </table>
     </div>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

I want to be able to pass in multiple objects at once so I can update all of them as once.  There's several issues I think that are going on.  I'm not sure why I have a NilClass when in my controllers I can call all of my observations:

```
def index
   @observation_reads = ObservationRead.all
   @readers = Reader.all.map { |reader| [reader.first_name, reader.id] }
end
```

I have a feeling if I get passed this error I'll have a routing issue because when I reworked this using a form_tag I can a `no route matches` when I've matched my routes.

```
namespace :admin do
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
  resources :readers, only: [:index]
  resources :observations
end
```

My routes are here: 
http://imgur.com/o2o7SHT

Can anyone help out with:

1. How to get passed this error message
2. Passing multiple objects in form
3. Updating the form to based on these objects that are being passed.

Here's the view I'm working with.  I simplified it in this post.

http://imgur.com/pjeANCB

Comment: Do it like this form_for :observations, url: [:admin, :observations] or form_for :observations, url: admin_observations_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
  form_for :observations, url: [:admin, :observations] do
```

or

```
   form_for :observations, url: admin_observations_path
```

Comment: So I like this solution but I want it to go to the update route cause I"m going to be updating multiple objects at the same time.  So I tried something like this that would try to send me to the update route:  `<%= form_for :observations, url: [:admin, :observation], method: :put do |f|  %>` but I get this error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/observations"}`

Comment: Basically, your solution got me passed the "no route matches error"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are passing an `Array` to `form_for`.

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @observation_reads] do |f|  %>
```

you should be passing an instance of `ObservationRead` and not `ObservationRead.all` to `form_for`

What does `form_for` do?

> Creates a form that allows the user to create or update the attributes
>   of a specific model object.

Comment: but rather than an instance, I want multiple objects to be updated.  That's why I specified ObservationRead.all any other suggestions?  I looked into collections for forms but couldn't figure out the documentation.